How can we get updated list using ssr of Next.js App Router?
I am getting data list using ssr of next app router.
I am going to remove one item of data by click.
I want to get data list what removed one item.
how to get the data list in next app router?
Shold I call getting data api at the CSR?

Can you please update your question it is not clear

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
